# C#: do the first 8 bytes copied by CopyPixels contain a header?

Tags: c#, imaging

I am using the CopyPixels method on a BitMapImage (C#) and want to get the raw pixel data. However, when I inspect the raw buffer in a debugger, I see that the first 8 bytes are always
(hex)

67174944 00300000

here's the snippet of code:

```
int stride = frm.PixelWidth * frm.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
stride = (stride % 4) == 0 ? stride : (stride + 4);
rawPixels = new byte[stride * frm.PixelHeight * frm.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8];
frm.CopyPixels(rawPixels, stride, 0);
```

I can't find any documentation that says what this header might be. Interestingly the text equivalent of 6717 is "DI", which made me think this had something to do with a DIB header, but I'm pretty sure I'm wrong there.
thanks.

Comment: How do you get "DI" from 0x6717?

Comment: yeah, I don't know. I looked at the hex window in the debugger and the text column on the right, which always said DI. I didn't look at it carefully enough.

Comment: oh, ok, it's 4944, not 6717 that is DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the array object header.  Add 8 to the address to find the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's wrong with the first 8 bytes, but some other remarks:

The calculation of the stride looks strange to me. What about

```
stride = ((stride+3)/4)*4;
```

Next, I guess the size of the rawPixels-buffer should read

```
rawPixels = new byte[stride * frm.PixelHeight]
```